# Firebase unable to write Security Rules for Unique Data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want my `vanNumber` to be unique

```
//vanwithagent is after  root "/vanwithagent"

vanwithagent : {
   "-KSHJyDyI49RpZwSkdg1" : { //
     "agentMobile" : "sdfs",
     "agentName" : "sdfsdf",
     "isAgentAssignedWithTask" : false,
     "vanName" : "fsdf",
     "vanNumber" : "sf",
     "vanPresentLocation" : {
       "currLattitude" : "N/A",
       "currLongitude" : "N/A",
       "pin" : "N/A"
     }
   }
 }
```

Rules I have written:

```
{
  "rules": { //Rules
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "vanwithagent": {
        "$vanwithagentId": {
            "vanNumber":{
                ".validate":"!(root.child('vanwithagent').child(data.child('vanNumber').val()).exists())"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot check if a *value* exists in a certain collection of values within Firebase's security rules. You can check if a certain key exists *and* if a key has a certain value. But this don't help you in this data model.

As usual the solution is to pick a data model that matches your requirements. If vans are unique and have an id, then store the list keyed under that id:

```
vanwithagent : {
   "sf" : { // vanNumber
     "agentMobile" : "sdfs",
     "agentName" : "sdfsdf",
     "isAgentAssignedWithTask" : false,
     "vanName" : "fsdf",
     "vanPresentLocation" : {
       "currLattitude" : "N/A",
       "currLongitude" : "N/A",
       "pin" : "N/A"
     }
   }
 }
```

This data structure *guarantees* that the van number is unique, without writing any security rules for it.